# Use session in a thread using MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, session, asynchronous

I am developing a MVC3 site that one action must download hundred of images, create a super big image and download it. To do such a thing I assumed that I could create a thread, do the job, update the session with the progress (#image) and finally save to server the completed file.

At the same time I would create a JavaScript that request data from the server and the server returns the session variables set from the thread.

I have created a thread process that does a time consuming job and update the progress using session but after the thread start the session is null.

Do you know what should I do to update the client with the process progress?

Comment: Your title might be misleading as what you want to achieve has nothing to do with the session, you only use it as a medium for temporary store. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322126/implementing-a-progress-bar-for-long-running-task-implemented-with-an-asp-net-mv or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx on info how to develop progress info on long running task. Mind you that whatever solution you use, it won't be very simple.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the naming.